# InflateException: Binary XML file line : Error inflating class <unknown>

Tags: android, android-layout

I am having a terrible time, this error happens on only one particular phone LG E405, has android version 2.3.6. The app works on every other device and emulator. All solution suggested in other cases dont apply to mine.

```
05-01 14:10:31.549: W/dalvikvm(3060): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x401ff560)
05-01 14:10:31.569: E/AndroidRuntime(3060): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-01 14:10:31.569: E/AndroidRuntime(3060): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{mf.sgh.activity/mf.sgh.activity.LoginScreenActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #29: Error inflating class 
05-01 14:10:31.569: E/AndroidRuntime(3060):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1658)
05-01 14:10:31.569: E/AndroidRuntime(3060):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1674)
05-01 14:10:31.569: E/AndroidRuntime(3060):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
05-01 14:10:31.569: E/AndroidRuntime(3060):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:942)
05-01 14:10:31.569: E/AndroidRuntime(3060):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-01 14:10:31.569: E/AndroidRuntime(3060):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
05-01 14:10:31.569: E/AndroidRuntime(3060):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3735)
05-01 14:10:31.569: E/AndroidRuntime(3060):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-01 14:10:31.569: E/AndroidRuntime(3060):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
05-01 14:10:31.569: E/AndroidRuntime(3060):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:904)
05-01 14:10:31.569: E/AndroidRuntime(3060):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:662)
05-01 14:10:31.569: E/AndroidRuntime(3060):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-01 14:10:31.569: E/AndroidRuntime(3060): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #29: Error inflating class 
05-01 14:10:31.569: E/AndroidRuntime(3060):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:518)
05-01 14:10:31.569: E/AndroidRuntime(3060):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
05-01 14:10:31.569: E/AndroidRuntime(3060):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:568)
05-01 14:10:31.569: E/AndroidRuntime(3060):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:623)
05-01 14:10:31.569: E/AndroidRuntime(3060):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:626)
05-01 14:10:31.569: E/AndroidRuntime(3060):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:408)
05-01 14:10:31.569: E/AndroidRuntime(3060):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
05-01 14:10:31.569: E/AndroidRuntime(3060):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
05-01 14:10:31.569: E/AndroidRuntime(3060):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.generateLayout(PhoneWindow.java:2240)
05-01 14:10:31.569: E/AndroidRuntime(3060):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.installDecor(PhoneWindow.java:2295)
05-01 14:10:31.569: E/AndroidRuntime(3060):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:203)
05-01 14:10:31.569: E/AndroidRuntime(3060):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1657)
05-01 14:10:31.569: E/AndroidRuntime(3060):     at mf.sgh.activity.LoginScreenActivity.onCreate(LoginScreenActivity.java:40)
05-01 14:10:31.569: E/AndroidRuntime(3060):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
05-01 14:10:31.569: E/AndroidRuntime(3060):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1622)
05-01 14:10:31.569: E/AndroidRuntime(3060):     ... 11 more
05-01 14:10:31.569: E/AndroidRuntime(3060): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
05-01 14:10:31.569: E/AndroidRuntime(3060):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
05-01 14:10:31.569: E/AndroidRuntime(3060):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:415)
05-01 14:10:31.569: E/AndroidRuntime(3060):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:505)
05-01 14:10:31.569: E/AndroidRuntime(3060):     ... 25 more
05-01 14:10:31.569: E/AndroidRuntime(3060): Caused by: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException
05-01 14:10:31.569: E/AndroidRuntime(3060):     at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1651)
05-01 14:10:31.569: E/AndroidRuntime(3060):     at android.provider.Settings$System.getSystemLocaleR2L(Settings.java:884)
05-01 14:10:31.569: E/AndroidRuntime(3060):     at android.provider.Settings$System.getCursorDirection(Settings.java:878)
05-01 14:10:31.569: E/AndroidRuntime(3060):     at android.widget.TextView.getImeWritingLanguageR2L(TextView.java:1045)
05-01 14:10:31.569: E/AndroidRuntime(3060):     at android.widget.TextView.chkCurrentDirection(TextView.java:1031)
05-01 14:10:31.569: E/AndroidRuntime(3060):     at android.widget.TextView.setPadding(TextView.java:1751)
05-01 14:10:31.569: E/AndroidRuntime(3060):     at android.view.View.(View.java:2264)
05-01 14:10:31.569: E/AndroidRuntime(3060):     at android.widget.TextView.(TextView.java:390)
05-01 14:10:31.569: E/AndroidRuntime(3060):     at android.widget.TextView.(TextView.java:383)
05-01 14:10:31.569: E/AndroidRuntime(3060):     ... 28 more
05-01 14:10:31.579: E/AndroidRuntime(3060): [Blue Error Handler] Make Debugging Report file for main
05-01 14:10:31.579: E/AndroidRuntime(3060): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{mf.sgh.activity/mf.sgh.activity.LoginScreenActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #29: Error inflating class 
05-01 14:10:31.579: E/AndroidRuntime(3060):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1658)
05-01 14:10:31.579: E/AndroidRuntime(3060):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1674)
05-01 14:10:31.579: E/AndroidRuntime(3060):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
05-01 14:10:31.579: E/AndroidRuntime(3060):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:942)
05-01 14:10:31.579: E/AndroidRuntime(3060):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-01 14:10:31.579: E/AndroidRuntime(3060):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
05-01 14:10:31.579: E/AndroidRuntime(3060):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3735)
05-01 14:10:31.579: E/AndroidRuntime(3060):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-01 14:10:31.579: E/AndroidRuntime(3060):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
05-01 14:10:31.579: E/AndroidRuntime(3060):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:904)
05-01 14:10:31.579: E/AndroidRuntime(3060):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:662)
05-01 14:10:31.579: E/AndroidRuntime(3060):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-01 14:10:31.579: E/AndroidRuntime(3060): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #29: Error inflating class 
05-01 14:10:31.579: E/AndroidRuntime(3060):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:518)
05-01 14:10:31.579: E/AndroidRuntime(3060):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
05-01 14:10:31.579: E/AndroidRuntime(3060):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:568)
05-01 14:10:31.579: E/AndroidRuntime(3060):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:623)
05-01 14:10:31.579: E/AndroidRuntime(3060):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:626)
05-01 14:10:31.579: E/AndroidRuntime(3060):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:408)
05-01 14:10:31.579: E/AndroidRuntime(3060):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
05-01 14:10:31.579: E/AndroidRuntime(3060):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
05-01 14:10:31.579: E/AndroidRuntime(3060):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.generateLayout(PhoneWindow.java:2240)
05-01 14:10:31.579: E/AndroidRuntime(3060):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.installDecor(PhoneWindow.java:2295)
05-01 14:10:31.579: E/AndroidRuntime(3060):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:203)
05-01 14:10:31.579: E/AndroidRuntime(3060):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1657)
05-01 14:10:31.579: E/AndroidRuntime(3060):     at mf.sgh.activity.LoginScreenActivity.onCreate(LoginScreenActivity.java:40)
05-01 14:10:31.579: E/AndroidRuntime(3060):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
05-01 14:10:31.579: E/AndroidRuntime(3060):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1622)
05-01 14:10:31.579: E/AndroidRuntime(3060):     ... 11 more
05-01 14:10:31.579: E/AndroidRuntime(3060): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
05-01 14:10:31.579: E/AndroidRuntime(3060):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
05-01 14:10:31.579: E/AndroidRuntime(3060):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:415)
05-01 14:10:31.579: E/AndroidRuntime(3060):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:505)
05-01 14:10:31.579: E/AndroidRuntime(3060):     ... 25 more
05-01 14:10:31.579: E/AndroidRuntime(3060): Caused by: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException
05-01 14:10:31.579: E/AndroidRuntime(3060):     at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1651)
05-01 14:10:31.579: E/AndroidRuntime(3060):     at android.provider.Settings$System.getSystemLocaleR2L(Settings.java:884)
05-01 14:10:31.579: E/AndroidRuntime(3060):     at android.provider.Settings$System.getCursorDirection(Settings.java:878)
05-01 14:10:31.579: E/AndroidRuntime(3060):     at android.widget.TextView.getImeWritingLanguageR2L(TextView.java:1045)
05-01 14:10:31.579: E/AndroidRuntime(3060):     at android.widget.TextView.chkCurrentDirection(TextView.java:1031)
05-01 14:10:31.579: E/AndroidRuntime(3060):     at android.widget.TextView.setPadding(TextView.java:1751)
05-01 14:10:31.579: E/AndroidRuntime(3060):     at android.view.View.(View.java:2264)
05-01 14:10:31.579: E/AndroidRuntime(3060):     at android.widget.TextView.(TextView.java:390)
05-01 14:10:31.579: E/AndroidRuntime(3060):     at android.widget.TextView.(TextView.java:383)
05-01 14:10:31.579: E/AndroidRuntime(3060):     ... 28 more
```

I really need help

Answer (score 0):

Suggestion : It may be possible that xml is not able to load the images due to which it goes Out of Memory and not able to Inflate the xml at the run time. Decrease the size of Images.

Comment: Do you mean all the images used in the application, the biggest size i have used is 9.47kb. Also i created a new project and then run just one activity and view which is failing in the main app and i got no errors.

Comment: Found the solution, error was from the locale being used by app. Activity was calling a locale which was not present on the phone

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to first make sure all strings are in the default language before entering them in the locale file.